# Fixing PATH for Python libraries using Bash

Tags: python, bash, macos, path, pip

I am attempting to install some Python libraries by executing variations of the following command in Bash:

```
pip install --user -U numpy
```

I installed Python3 using Homebrew.

I then get variations of the following message each time:

> WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.7 are installed in '/Users/x/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

How can I fix this issue to avoid problems in the future?

Comment: Dylan below is correct however it is not a must-do-thing. You can just turn the warning error off if you dont want to add it to the environment path as stated in the warning `--no-warn-script-location`

Comment: @Barb - good point. If you're using pip to install stuff, having the pip directory on your path is usually a good idea.

Comment: For sure! I cant really think of one reason why you wouldn't want to have it in your path

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The error message is telling you to add Python 3 to your path.

To do that, use a text editor to open `/Users/<you>/.profile`, and as the very last line add:

```
export PATH=/Users/<you>/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH
```

Then you'll need to launch a new Terminal window for those settings to take effect. (you could make it take effect in your current shell by entering the line directly into your shell)

[Edit: now that macOS 12.3 has removed all versions of Python, Homebrew is the easiest way to install Python. Fortunately things are simpler because there's only one version of Python on your system and you won't need to override the system's version (because there isn't one any longer).]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is `.bash_history`, `.bash_profile`, and `.bash_sessions`, but no `.bashrc`?

Comment: Ok, I created a new `.bashrc` file by using the command `echo >> ~/.bashrc`, as specified by the Hastur's answer https://superuser.com/questions/584540/no-bashrc-file-in-my-home-directory

Comment: You could have used `echo export PATH=/Users/you/Library/Python/3.7/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc` to add it to your path. Using an editor lets you see the other stuff in your `.bashrc` which is your case was nothing.  Happy to help.

Comment: And what is the point when Mac's python is v2? Nothing in that new path would work, right?

Comment: @wick - macOS Python has long been able to have 2.7 and 3.x coexist. Apple (and everyone else) will eventually no longer support v2, but in the meantime, many users will need to have both versions available. I'm 95% migrated to Python 3.x. This is off-this-topic, so I won't elaborate.

Comment: @DylanMcNamee yes, somehow it works for me, even though `python --version` is still v2. I suppose it is mercy of each software package to determine how/which python it is calling..

Comment: I am getting this message when I run the .bashrc command: no such file or directory: /Users/<myname>/.bashrc

Answer (score 25):

Update: As of python 3.8, the following path should be used:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:$PATH
```

If you're using **bash**, you can store this in your `/.bashrc` 
If you're using **zsh**, you can store this in your `/.zshrc`

Comment: could you describe the sequence of steps to follow here? I'm a bit lost

Answer (score 3):

You have to update the seeking path location, to needed `bin` folder, in your `.zshrc`, `.bashrc` etc.

##### Example

For `/Library/Python/3.8/bin`,
you can prepend the variable `$HOME`, and use with the needed path:

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH"
```

#### Epilogue

In current `Terminal` tab, you have to reload your shell, with the config, by `. ~/.zshrc`, or `.bashrc` etc