# python -m textblob.download_corpora => No module named textblob

Tags: python

I am currently running jupyter notebooks on a Raspberry Pi Zero W. I was trying to download textblob through terminal. The "pip install -U textblob" downloaded. However, I received the following:

**"WARNING: The script tqdm is installed in '/home/pi/.local/bin' which is not on PATH..." for each script.**

When I went to execute the second line **"python -m textblob.download_corpora"** - I just get **"No module named textblob"**

As you can probably guess, I'm quite new to all of this and trying to learn as I go. Please help! :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm if you have python2.x as well as python3 on your RPie. If yes you should use pip3 install -U textblob

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing PATH for Python libraries using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58051467/fixing-path-for-python-libraries-using-bash)

Comment: Thanks! The pip3 install fixed the warnings! 
Alas, the python -m textblob.download_corpora is still giving the same error: /usr/bin/python: No module named textblob

Answer (score 0):

just put **python3 -m textblob.download_corpora** in terminal

Works for me.