# Download the new python on MacOS but still got the old version when asking for python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, updates

I am transforming from windows to Macos and want to install python. It came with an old version of python 2.7 in the computer, so I download python 3 using the `pyenv install` command. But when I input `python --version`, I still got the old version. Why is that? And I can't install `pip` either. Anybody knows why?

Comment: The existing Python 2.7 is being used by the operating system. You can't (and shouldn't) upgrade that. Your new interpreter can be used by typing `python3` or using the full path (i.e. `/foo/bar/bin/python3`).

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you! So does that mean for all python command, I need to use `python3 --version`, etc?

Comment: Whenever you want to use Python 3, yes. You can also use the shebang method for your own scripts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670303/purpose-of-usr-bin-python3

Comment: The above method did not change the output of python --version for me (using a mac Big Sur OS). The accepted solution of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58051467/fixing-path-for-python-libraries-using-bash) helped. It seems like the PATH that is referred to for finding python environment needs to be modified in ~/.bashrc or **~/.zshrc** (for newer macOS users).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have installed python 3 (check it by running `python3 --version`), you can set python3 as a default python version by creating a symbolic link.

run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*` to see where all versions are installed.

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  69 May 10  2019 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  76 May 10  2019 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  71 May 10  2019 /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  78 May 10  2019 /usr/local/bin/python3.7-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  72 May 10  2019 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  79 May 10  2019 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config
```

The output is like above, now you just need to choose the version you want from the ones which end with `...python3.X` **not** `...-config` or `...python3.Xm`, and create a symbolic link to it.

For example, you have chosen `python3.7` to run as a default version, now it's time to create the symbolic link by running:

`ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python`

now if you run `python --version` its output should be 3.7

Comment: That solution didn't help me on OS 10.15 Catalina

Comment: did not work on Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @Threem's answer, if you have the same issue with pip and pip3 (python's package manager) then you can run the following:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/pip*
```

You'll see something similar to his answer, but with pip instead of python.

Then you can create a symbolic link the same way.

```
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/pip3.10 /usr/local/bin/pip
```

Now if you run

```
pip --version
```

you'll get your pip3 version.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets hit with the "permission denied" error you can instead just do:

```
alias python=python3
```